# Foundation Crack in my house

Tags: concrete, foundation, waterproofing

I just noticed a crack in the foundation,
at the beginning i thought it is parging crack but it seems deeper to the foundation.

by googling I found many methods of how to fix the crack, some use epoxy and some use special concrete mix, some wires.

not sure which method is the best to fix the foundation cracks.

is this something require a professional or I can do it by myself?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's on the other side of that wall, dirt, basement?

Comment: If there's no water problem, then this is a finish problem. I'd repair the stucco, but get a line of stretchy, paintable sealant over the crack. Paint the whole thing and forget about it.

Comment: @JACK this is a good question.
I checked the other side and it seems dirt, it is just at the area between the garage and the house on top and under is dirt and basement I will edit my question and add drawing. Please check it

Comment: i'd only go to the trouble of fixing the below ground piece if it was leading to a leak inside.  you typically do a tar / mesh tape / tar repair below grade to prevent water entering.  the concrete people have large rolls of a fiber like tape similar to fibafuse 6" wide that you embed into the tar and then tar overtop.

Comment: I agree with @popham on this.  Monitor it for further issues but treat it as a finish problem unless it causes further issues.  As far as can you do this yourself if it is serious foundation problem...  Yes...  Should you?  Absolutely not.  Last summer I dug under the foundation of my grandmothers split level home to diagnose a serious water leak caused by the root system of a Silver Maple...  It sucked.  At base, you have to be willing to jack the house.  You should also have taken college level physics and the calculus series at a MINIMUM before you approach a serious foundation repair.

Comment: @ChuckTerry  Foundation cracks are quite common and usually a simple fix with some back breaking work digging.  Tree roots lifting or cracked footings is much more involved work.  This looks like a simple crack, maybe caused by settling.

Comment: @crip, my theory was that transitioning from a deeper basement wall to a shorter stem wall caused poor compaction under the shorter stem wall (workers are afraid of breaking something by overcompacting beside a drop off). The crack bends in the wrong direction for that theory, though, unless the plan drawing is mirrored.